# How to remove element from Array and child from stage

Tags: actionscript-3

So I am currently attempting to remove an element from the array 'zombie_horde' as well as remove the child from the stage. My aimed result, a movie clip that is part of an array israndomly played and when finished playing, the frame changes to a gameover frame.
This is my code:

part of the big loop:

```
for each (var zom:Betherino in zombie_horde)

{
var frame = zom.currentFrame
trace(frame)
if(frame == zom.lastframe)
    {
        updatearray()
    }
    else{
    zom.gotoAndStop(frame+1)
    }
```

functions:

```
function updatearray()
{

zombie_horde.splice();

trace('spliced')
}


function removeBetherino()
{

stage.removeChild(Betherino)
}
```

This is what I have so far. I am wondering how I am supposed to continue to tackle this situation of removing the movie clip (AS Linkage 'Betherino') from not only the array but also the stage

Sorry I am still new to stack Overflow :(
I havent gotten up to the change frame part any suggestions on ideas would be great!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You want it not only to remove an element from an array and from the stage... but it also needs to go to a gameover frame... and it's randomly selected? Huh?

Comment: Remove the element from the array and the stage then go to a gameover frame sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "Remove the element from the array and the stage then go to a gameover frame", there's three steps:

- Remove the element from the array
- Remove the element from stage
- Jump to a game over frame.

The last one, I think that's best left to you. There's no code related to gameover frames in your question, so I can't help you there.

The other elements, however...

```
for each (var zom:Betherino in zombie_horde){
    var frame = zom.currentFrame
    trace(frame)
    if(frame == zom.lastframe)
    {
        updatearray()
    }
    else{
        zom.gotoAndStop(frame+1)
    }
}
```

You go through each zombie in the zombie horde, and if it's at its last frame, you try to remove it.

This implies that these zombies simply play through an animation and then disappear. Sounds strange to me. Is that really want you want the code to do?

Next... you use `updatearray` to remove the zombies from the array. But you do so via `zombie_horde.splice()`. That doesn't work. If you look at the [documentation for `splice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice()) then you'll see that it takes 2+ arguments: `startIndex:int, deleteCount:uint, ... values`. That is, the first argument is the start index to start deleting at, the second argument specifies how many you want to delete, and any arguments after that are added back in the list.

```
zombie_horde.splice(zombie_horde.indexOf(zom), 1);
```

will do what you're looking for, when inlined.

As for removing the element from stage, you need to pass an object. `stage.removeChild(Betherino)` is not the correct way, inline and use `stage.removeChild(zom)` instead. That makes for this function:

```
for each (var zom:Betherino in zombie_horde){
    var frame = zom.currentFrame
    trace(frame)
    if(frame == zom.lastframe)
    {
        zombie_horde.splice(zombie_horde.indexOf(zom), 1);
        stage.removeChild(zom);
        //go to gameover frame and exit for loop
    }
    else{
        zom.gotoAndStop(frame+1)
    }
}
```

The "go to gameover frame" comment still needs to be replaced with the relevant code.

Comment: Wow thanks! But for some reason in the output i get, ArgumentError #2025: the supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Comment: @Pita that means `zom` is not on the stage.

Comment: Oh i was trying to remove betherino a movie clip from the stage

Comment: Then you did so many things wrong that you need to take a good hard look at the documentation.

Comment: Ok, sorry im really new to this programming thing.

Comment: Zom is not on the stage, Betherino_mc is on the stage and with as linkage of Betherino

Comment: @Pita Then you need to remove `Betherino_mc`. Does it work if you use `stage.removeChild(Betherino_mc)`?

Comment: When i changed Betherino_mc to Betherin_mc it would say access of undefined property. But when the instance name had a similar name to that of the child being removed from the stage the error in outputpopped up error#2025 the supplied display object must be a child of the caller

Comment: Currently the movie clip Betherino finishes the animation and just sits there. Whenever i try to tweak my code i get coercian errors

Comment: According to your code, `zombie_horde` is an array of objects that are of type `Bitherino`. You are referencing each object within the `zombie_horde` array as `zom` and you are attempting to remove them from the stage via `removeChild`. But later state that zom is not on stage. I think that you are getting confused between what a variable (reference) and a class are. Your variable `zom` is of type (class) `Bitherino`. You may also be running into trouble with _the display object must be a child of the caller_ depending on where your code is located. Where is this code located? Main timeline?

Comment: yes it is (code is on main timeline) and you are correct as to me getting that error.

Comment: @C. Parcell i took ur comment under consideration and i did it! Thanks :P now i need to find a way to exit the loop.